# How to load all my computer's installed fonts into a PDF with Apache PDFBox?

Tags: java, fonts, itext, pdfbox

How to load **system fonts** in Apache PDFBox? I want my application to be able to choose any installed font for my PDF, just like I can choose a font in Libre Office or Microsoft Word.

Does PDFBox have an equivalent to iText's `FontFactory.registerDirectories()`?

1. I need PDFBox to be aware of the fonts installed on my PC.
2. I need a way to load a font into a PDF by its **family name** rather than its **font files**.
3. I want to be able to specify, simply, family + bold/italic.  I shouldn't have to know whether Arial.ttf and Arial-Bold.ttf are two separate font files.

Most extant examples of loading fonts in Apache PDFBox involve the function call below, but this function takes only a direct path to the font file, not the family name:

```
PDType0Font font = PDType0Font.load(document, new File("path/to/font-file.ttf"));
```

Here is a hardship, because:

- JavaFX's `Font.getFamilies()` returns only family names, not paths. `PDType0Font.load()` takes only paths.
- Java AWT's `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts()` returns `Font` objects, which have family names, but no paths. Again, `PDType0Font.load()` takes only paths.
- I could walk the list of system folders from iText's `FontFactory.registerDirectories()` source code, but then I am dealing with paths, not family names. I won't know how to determine family names, nor how to group Arial and Arial Bold as a single font (family) in my application.
- PDFBox's `new FontFileFinder().find()` returns URI paths to files, not family names. Same problem: I want my users to select from a list of *fonts*, not *files*.
- PDFBox's `for (FontInfo info : FontProvider.getFontInfo())` and also `FontCache().getFont(FontInfo)` seem to provide a clue, but I've found no examples on how to use them.

Supposing there is no such `registerSystemFonts()` method in PDFBox, I am open to a custom-code solution.  But, if the only way is to copy all the needful source code from iText's `registerDirectories` and adapting it to PDFBox with hacks, I'd like to know where to begin.

Comment: I think the best is that you copy "FileSystemFontProvider.java" and use that one. The FontInfo class gives the name and more information. You could extend it so that it also returns the path.

Comment: Thank you. I will look at it.

Answer (score 2):

To load a system font into a PDF by its family name:

```java
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.*;

...
var mapping = FontMappers.instance().getTrueTypeFont(fontName, null);
if (mapping != null && mapping.getFont() != null && !mapping.isFallback()) {
    try {
        return PDType0Font.load(document, mapping.getFont().getOriginalData());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.warn("load font error", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Inspired by [link](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeFont/close)

Answer (score 0):

In FileSystemFontProvider.java, you can see the following lines to get system fonts' path

```
        FontFileFinder fontFileFinder = new FontFileFinder();
        List<URI> fonts = fontFileFinder.find();

        for (URI font : fonts) {
            logger.info("Font: " + font.getPath());

        }
```

Comment: Same problem. I can load a font from the URI, but how do I determine the font name from the URI, so that the user interface can present the font names to the user to select from?